# How to run a command in each sub directory within a given directory in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a command in each sub-directory within a directory
For example I could have the structure as follows:

```
Dir1
--Dir2.imageAssets
----file1.pdf
----file1.metadata
--Dir3
----Dir4.imageAssets
------file2.pdf
------file2.metadata
```

I would run a script that would check in each directory if we have a pdf and if so convert it to another image type. Then I will modify the `.metadata` file to change the file extension.
In my case I want to walk through every sub directory and run the conversion script within a directory with suffix `.imageAssets`.

I've seen `os.walk` which has all the paths, directories and files within the file but would I then have to recursively call into each dir the function again or is there a simpler way?

Open to any ideas if there's a simpler solution

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to say. Clearly you need to descend the tree recursively, and odds are, `os.walk` is what you want here; it already processes recursively for you, and each loop would correspond to one directory being processed.

Comment: Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using os_walk as I'd wrote in the original question and per the comment:

```
def walk_path(file_path):
        for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(file_path):
                if path.endswith('.imageset'):
                        convert_pdfs_in_dir(path)
```